# How to display int value obtained from spinner in android

Tags: int, settext, android-spinner

I am trying to convert a spinner value that i get (based off the position) into an int value which i can then display below the spinner. When i run the code it gets an error when i include the "tv.setText(position);" line but i cant figure out why. I am trying ot set the text of the TextView tv to the position of the spinner.

What am i doing wrong?

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.AdapterView; 
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 
import android.widget.Spinner; 
import android.widget.TextView;  
public class TestThings extends Activity {      
Spinner spinner1;   
int yourInt;    
TextView tv;    
@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
setContentView(R.layout.testing);       
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.testspinner1);                       
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(              this, R.array.chpugsp1_array,               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);        
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){                
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,                  int arg2, long arg3) {
int position  = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testext);
tv.setText(position);
}           
@Override            
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {                
// TODO Auto-generated method stub                          }                   
});     
}  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
tv.setText(""+ position);
```